# No Functions Found. Try making job classes and methods public

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var host = new JobHost();
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }

    public static void ProcessMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("Topic", "Subscription")] BrokeredMessage message)
    {
        //TO DO(message);
    }
}
```

I am running code Local m/c.

In above code I am trying to trigger Topic's subscription on entry.

but when I run Code It gave me error

> No Functions Found. Try making job classes and methods public

I tried same method in public Function class, but doesn't work.

But when I changed ServiceBusTrigger to QueueTrigger It worked.

I have set below config properly.

```
<add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="{Connection string}"/>

<add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="{Connection_String}"/>    

<add name="AzureWebJobsServiceBus" connectionString="{Connection_String}"/>
```

Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to interact with the Service Bus or with the Queue?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're using the latest prerelease v1.1.0 version? In that version we made a change, which requires you to call **config.UseServiceBus()** in your startup code. The ServiceBus bindings are now extensions (like the rest of the external binding extensions in [azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions](http://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions) and must now be registered explicitly.

This change is also discussed in this [blog post](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/extensible-triggers-and-binders-with-azure-webjobs-sdk-1-1-0-alpha1/).